# event data in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I just started playing around with pixi and have drawn multiple rectangles from an array with pixel coordinates like this:

```
var rectangle = [....];
....


var stage = new PIXI.Stage();
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(wrapper.getWidth(), wrapper.getHeight(), { transparent: true });
....


var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.interactive = true;


graphics.on("mouseover", function(e) {
   this.alpha = 0.5;

}).on("mouseout", function() {
   this.alpha = 1;

});


graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);


for (var i = 0; i < rectangle.length; i++) {
   graphics.drawRect(rectangle[i][0], rectangle[i][1], 10, 10);

}


graphics.endFill();


stage.addChild(graphics);
renderer.render(stage);
```

The events are triggered but the object I get by "e" or "this" inside the callback is the object for all graphics. I want to get that single "mouseovered" rectangles object I can see in the graphicsData, but there is no id or anything to identify it by. How can I do this?

Performance is of essence as I'm going to render 20k+ rectangles or circles.

Answer (score 2):

Without drawing each rectangle onto it's own `PIXI.Graphics` object you won't be able to get individual `mouseover` events. This is because as far as PIXI is concerned the Graphics object is a single bitmap image.

I would suggest performing your own hit tests inside the `mouseover` function to detect which rectangle the cursor is over.

If you are using `PIXI.Rectangle`s you can take advantage of the built in `Rectangle.Contains` function to check if a point (in this case the mouse position) is inside the bounds.